# US working visa/ESTA

Tags: visas, usa, esta, working-visas, texas

I am currently working in the U.S on a H2B visa but I want to stay a couple of weeks longer than what my visa allows. I have a current valid ESTA, can I just stay in the country or must I leave the country first? For example, I fly from my location here in San Francisco to Mexico and then fly to Texas (my destination).

Comment: Leaving and entering almost certainly works.  You can also apply to USCIS to change your nonimmigrant status without leaving the country.  The cost of doing this IIRC is fairly high.

Comment: Are the "couple of weeks" for continuing your work? Is it the H-2B _visa_ or your _immigration status_ that expires, or both?

Comment: @CGCampbell: A visa has *nothing* to do with permission to stay in the US. A visa is only for entry. It's the status and duration of the I-94 that determines ability to stay in the US.